# Comparing a character to series of characters

Tags: c, char

Is there a more convenient way of checking if a character is equal to any of the following characters without it being so unappealing?

```
int NormalSearch(char* Line,char* Word)
```

'
'
'

```
if(Word[j]!='|' && Word[j]!='{' && Word[j]!='}' 
   && Word[j]!='[' && Word[j]!=']' && Word[j]!='.')
```

Comment: `if (!strchr("|{}[].", Word[j])) {}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function:

```
#include <string.h>
...
if (strchr("|{}[].", Word[j]) == NULL) // character not found
    ...
```

---

If somehow you can't or must not use the string.h header, you can easily create your own version:

```
char * my_strchr(char * haystack, char needle)
{
    if (!haystack)
        return NULL;

    while (*haystack && *haystack != needle)
        ++haystack;

    return *haystack || *haystack == needle ? haystack : NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [`strchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr). That's a *concise* approach.

Alternatively, use of a `switch` case can also be made, but it's not recommended.

```
switch (Word[j])
{
    case '|':
    case '{':
    case '}':
    case ']':
    case '[':
    case '.':
        // come out of switch, don't do anything
        break;

    default:
        // no match
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char * t= "|{}[].";

while ( *t && *t != Word[j] ) t++;

if ( *t == 0 )
{
    //
}
```